# Destination port unreachable in my udp client socket

Tags: c, sockets

```
int  udp_sock() {
    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0);

    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
    }

    puts("Socket created.......\n");

    server1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.210.110.10");
    server1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server1.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //Connect to remote server
    con= connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server1 , sizeof(server1));

    if(con<0) {
        perror("connect failed. Error\n");
        return con;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The packet is reaching server mentioned, but the error *"destination port unreachable"* comes up in Wireshark.

1. How to assign a UDP port on my client to receive data on a particular port?
2. How to assign two different ports - 1024 and 1025 to receive data?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: "The packet is reaching server mentioned" - How are you sure? Where in the code are you sending the packet?

Comment: Yeah - like @Prabhu comments below, connect() is not defined for UDP:(

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a server waiting on the other end. A simple way for testing is to use netcat.

```
nc -lu 8053
```

Alternatively set up a utility that is designed for udp testing, such as echo server. This is normally built into an inetd or xinetd server

If you want to intercept incoming udp packets you will need to use bind() select()/poll()/epoll() and recvfrom()

Comment: One cannot listen on datagram sockets.

Comment: @Prabhu One can definitely listen on datagram sockets, it's just that you don't establish actual connection sessions but rather just receive packets which you may then send back.